Function input conditional object keys based on value of other keys
I would like to have a function whose input object keys are statically typed depending on the given value of some key. Here is a TypeScript playground with a failing test:
Playground Link
export type Input<$Method extends URL | 'memory'> = {
  method: $Method
} & ($Method extends URL ? { headers?: HeadersInit } : {})

declare const foo: <$Input extends Input<URL | 'memory'>>(input:$Input) => $Input

foo({ method: new URL('http://abc'), headers: {} }) // OK
foo({ method: new URL('http://abc') }) // OK
foo({ method: 'memory' }) // OK

// @ts-expect-error headers should be disallowed
foo({ method: 'memory', headers:{} })
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^ -- should error

In the above, notice that headers should only be allowed when method is URL type.  But I have not solved how to achieve this. How can it be done?
Also notice that the inferred type is available in the output position (return).
-- edit
One solution I found is using an Exact type helper, but is there a simpler way?
link

I found a solution using an Exact type helper (link), but is there a simpler way? -- I've added a link to the original post.

I don't see why Input is generic (since you only every use Input<URL | 'memory'>) or why you're using conditional types (since they get evaluated when $Method is specified as URL | 'memory'.  If I were writing this I'd just make Input a union, and in that union I'd disallow headers explicitly for the union member with "memory", as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thanks, I ended up toward your solution, except used an Exact type instead of your approach of headers?: never. I prefer the never approach since it's presumably much cheaper for TypeScript to compute that type. Something that my solution and yours suffer from is that there is autocomplete for headers even when the method is memory. How can that be fixed? Other than that, I accept your solution!

If you want headers to be rejected and you want foo to be generic, then it needs to be mentioned and therefore TS will "helpfully" autosuggest it (even though it will reject anything except undefined).  I can't fix that. Does that mean I should or should not write an answer?

When working with discriminated unions in other contexts, TypeScript doesn't have this issue. But for this case if it cannot get better than your draft solution, I will accept it. I think it would be worthwhile to mention the usability limitation in your answer. Perhaps some future TypeScript release can enable a better solution without that limitation.

"When working with discriminated unions in other contexts, TypeScript doesn't have this issue." Only if every union member has a discriminant property type. URL is not a literal, so no matter what,  { method: "memory" } | { method: URL, headers?: HeadersInit } will suggest headers even if method is "memory". I'm not sure why this is a limitation of my answer instead of a limitation of your structure. You could make it method: "url", url: URL, headers?: HeadersInit and then we could fix the autosuggest. But it's sort of orthogonal to what you're asking. I'll mention it but ‍♂️

I think your answer is amazing. What I meant was that, from a DX point of view, which is a driving motivation of TS I think, a simpler solution here would trade off the requirement of an additional field users need to input. In this case I am considering the act of forcing the user to do more (input a DU field value) a negative.

Your generic Input<$Method> type doesn't really do what you want when $Method is the union type URL | 'memory'.  It is equivalent to { method: "memory" | URL; } | { method: "memory" | URL; headers?: HeadersInit; } which is effectively just { method: "memory" | URL; headers?: HeadersInit; }, and thus there is nothing that prohibits or even discourages headers when method is "memory".
Since you're only actually using Input<URL | 'memory'> in foo(), you don't actually need Input to be generic at all; once you decide what Input<URL | 'memory'> should actually be, you can just replace Input with that.  The obvious choice would be to make it a discriminated union like
type Input = { method: "memory" } | { method: URL, headers?: HeadersInit }

and if foo were not a generic function, that would behave as desired, assuming you pass an object literal so that excess property checks would kick in:
declare const foo: (input: Input) => Input
foo({ method: new URL('http://abc'), headers: {} }) // OK
foo({ method: new URL('http://abc') }) // OK
foo({ method: 'memory' }) // OK
foo({ method: 'memory', headers: {} }) // error 

but since foo is generic and $Input is just constrained to Input, then extra properties will be accepted:
declare const foo: <$Input extends Input>(input: $Input) => $Input
foo({ method: new URL('http://abc'), headers: {} }) // OK
foo({ method: new URL('http://abc') }) // OK
foo({ method: 'memory' }) // OK
foo({ method: 'memory', headers: {} }) // OK again, uh oh 

To actually prohibit headers when method is "memory", you'll need to mention it in that union member as being impossible, like this:
type Input = { method: "memory", headers?: never } | { method: URL, headers?: HeadersInit }

An optional property of the never type means that the property is either missing/undefined, or it's of the never type, and there are no values of that type.  So it has to be missing or undefined in practice:
foo({ method: new URL('http://abc'), headers: {} }) // OK
foo({ method: new URL('http://abc') }) // OK
foo({ method: 'memory' }) // OK    
foo({ method: 'memory', headers: {} }) // error! 

So that's the type for Input I'd suggest.

Note that in both definitions of Input above, you will get foo() to auto-suggest headers, even if the type turns out to be prohibited.  There's not much I can do there because URL isn't a valid discriminant property by itself (it needs to be a literal type for that.  "memory" works, you can still discriminate on method in practice).
If I wanted to address that I might forget about fixing Input and instead split foo into two overloads, where the "memory" call signature doesn't mention headers directly as a key. That would look like
declare const foo: {
    <$Input extends { method: "memory" }>(input: $Input): $Input;
    <$Input extends { method: URL, headers?: HeadersInit }>(input: $Input): $Input;
}

foo({ method: new URL('http://abc'), headers: {} }) // OK
foo({ method: new URL('http://abc') }) // OK
foo({ method: 'memory' }) // OK
foo({ method: 'memory', headers: {} }); // no autosuggest but STILL OK 

But you still need to do some work to prohibit it, leading to the following complicated mess which starts to look like an Exact helper:
declare const foo: {
    <$Input extends { method: "memory" } & Record<"headers" & keyof $Input, never>>(
        input: $Input): $Input;
    <$Input extends { method: URL, headers?: HeadersInit }>(input: $Input): $Input;
}
foo({ method: new URL('http://abc'), headers: {} }) // OK
foo({ method: new URL('http://abc') }) // OK
foo({ method: 'memory' }) // OK
foo({ method: 'memory', headers: {} }); // no autosuggest and error! 

Now you'll only be suggested headers when calling the second overload. Excess properties are still not rejected because it's generic, so you can call foo({method: new URL(""), foo: 1, bar: "", baz: true}) and not get errors.  But if you try to do it with headers you will get an error because Record<"headers" & keyof $Input, never> will not be satisfied.
Playground link to code
